Dissolve neighbour polygons when distance is below X meters
I like to dissolve polygons in QGIS which are separated by small gaps (streets or paths...). As shown in the picture below, the two polygons in the north should be dissolved, excluding the one in the south.
My approach would be something like select by expression and the something like nearest neighour and then dissolve. I have multiple polygons in my project area. The goal is not to dissolve them altogether but create fewer polygons out of these which are close together (e. g. 5 m or less)
How to do this ?



Run "Points along geometry" and choose a suitable distance, e.g. 1m
Run "DBSCAN Clustering" on your generated points with a minimum cluster size of one and your preferred maximum distance, e.g. 5m
Run "Join Attributes by location" with your polygons as join layer and the clustered points as compare layer. Choose intersects as predicate, the CLUSTER_ID field to add and one-to-one as join-type
Run "Dissolve" on your joined layer and choose the CLUSTER_ID field as dissolve field

Done:


awesome ! works like a charm!
